# Check if user is on page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm building a one on one chat application that allows users to host rooms. Just to give a little more feedback:

1. User creates room (rooms are public, anybody can view but if user hasn't signed up, chat will be disabled and user will be prompted to sign up for chat.)
2. Other users sign up for room
3. Users chat with host based on order they signed up

I would like to show if the host is online or not. Or to go one step further, show if the host is in the room.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, this things work as following.

Every time user take actions (chat refresh, message sent, page visited, etc) a token associated to the user (token that is saved in your server, DB for example) is updated with current time.

```
| User ID     | Last action         |
-------------------------------------
| 14 (mark)   | 2012-02-09-10:34:53 |
| 56 (phil)   | 2012-02-09-09:12:34 |
|  9 (john)   | 2012-02-09-10:33:11 |
```

And then you decide an user is *online* if his token is not too old (5/10 minutes?)

You can improve this method if you use AJAX to send a periodical request to server every 1 minute or so. This AJAX request update the token value. So, this way, you can tell the user is online also if he does nothing but stare at the page. And when he quit (close browser or tab), AJAX periodical call stops works, so after 5/10 minutes the user is declared *offline*.

Good luck!

Comment: So I need to create a table and send the host's actions, and then check it for that user's id had any activity in a certain time interval.

Comment: In codeigniter you can use a [filter](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Filters_system) before each controller action to check if a user is logged in and update the token if they are.

Comment: @ciprian Exactly. If you already have a table for users (and I think you have!), you can also just add a new column to that table. You choice :)

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I will also try out the filters in CI. They look very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

assume you have 5 people in the room (and one or more are bound to be active), do these:

- for every action a user takes (be it a keystroke or an actual message sending), "ping" the server (send it a message that you exist) and log it (in your database perhaps) the the time that event took place. (notice how facebook has that *"User is typing..."* - this is it.
- in turn for sending that action (via ajax i suppose), the reply of the server is a list of users in that room that are online and not online. do this by comparing the current time with the time of last activity for each user inside (current time - last active time = time away)
- knowing who's online and not, rebuild the "chat mate list" in your browser

you can do a multitude of possibilities. like say allow 5 minutes or else, that user is idle. if the difference in time 15 minutes or more, consider that person off.

you can also take a step further by pinging the server for an update on who's online regularly, otherwise called a "heartbeat" instead of having to do it by keystroke or every message send. procedure it the same: tell the server you are online, log your existence, and have it return a list of chat mates.

do note that in this application (browser chat), there is no way that the server knows that you are offline, closed your browser etc. that's why you need that "heartbeat" as well as logging your actions regularly.

as for host... you should tag that room with the host id and the heartbeat will tell you if he's still online.